# Updating Editor and Modified for a publishing page

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to update a publishing page in SharePoint 2010 with new `Editor` and `Modified` values, but the ones I pass (that I copy from another page) are not saved.

I've tried `Update()`, `SystemUpdate()`, `UpdateOverwriteVersion()` - nothing works. Is there a secret trick? :)

Code snippet below:

```
...
$page = $web.Lists["Pages"].GetItemByUniqueId($uid)
$page["Editor"] = $e      # user from another page
$page["Modified"] = $m    # date from another page
$page.SystemUpdate($false)
```